# Publish Error- VS 2010- Configuration File Changed?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config, iis-5

I am publishing a web page to a local server through VS2010- I haven't published anything new in a couple days and I haven't made any config changes(I think). I have been following my same process for 4-5 months.

Publish shows as succeeded, and my hosted directory on the local machine is showing my changes(I can also debug in VS w/o isses). I am in windows XP and am running IIS 5.1.

When I hit the site from an outside place- my changes do not show up. A subset of the pages (ones requiring specific access rights) show this error:

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The configuration file has been changed by another program.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: C:\Hosting\XXXX\web.config

Comment: Same problem here with vs2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restart of my machine fixed the issue (I thought i restarted first, but I realized something blocked it- and I was distracted and didn't notice).